# In Android, how to remove View's of parentView?

Tags: android

As follows, I had removed childView from his parent. But I found the ChildView's parent not as NUll。And I also found the souces code of  ViewGroup's method of removeView() hasn't disposed of ChildView's  variable "mParent".

```
 if (null != mTextView.getParent() && mTextView.getParent() != mLl) {
                ((ViewGroup) mTextView.getParent()).removeView(mTextView);
            }
if (mTextView.getParent() != mLl)
   mLl.addView(mTextView);
```

when executing mLl.addView(mTextView), it would throw IllegalStateException of "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

So how should  I do?

Comment: If you are dynamically adding and removing views, you should use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: remove mTextView from xml and add it dynamically

Comment: I know that ways,but I have this requirement,so I need use this way to do .So you can tell me why it's wrong ,not  other ways .